# The JSP specification requires that an attribute name is preceded by whitespace - Tomcat error

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7, jsp-tags

I'm getting an error in one of my jsp page while deploying my application on Tomcat server.

Error is as follow :

> SEVERE org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
>   Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /content/jsp/RequestUpdate.jsp
>   (line: 1234, column: 183) The JSP specification requires that an
>   attribute name is preceded by whitespace.

and line 1234 look like this:

```
<html:select property="countryName"  size="1" tabindex="6" styleClass="modulecontent" value="<%=pdmReq.getCountryName()%>" onchange="javascript:makeDefault(this,this.form.segment)";>
```

Comment: can you try putting the onchange semoicolon within the quotes??  onchange="javascript:makeDefault(this,this.form.segment)"; to onchange="javascript:makeDefault(this,this.form.segment);"

Comment: Thanks Feu, After putting the semicolon whitespace error is gone but now I am getting "Unterminated &lt;html:select tag" in the same line.